# Есть ли возможность переместить все дочерние элементы в другой элемент и удалить пустой?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, dom

У меня есть элемент

```
<ul>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>
<div></div>
```

Есть ли возможность переместить все дочерние элементы `ul` в `div` при этом удалить пустой элемент, чтобы получилась такая конструкция:

```
<div>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
</div>
```

Дополнения:
требуется добавить children в shadowRoot. 
Вариант который меня устроил в данный момент использовать не div а template

```
<template>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
</template>
```

Дальше в коде делаю clone и копирую.

```
     let clone = document.importNode(el.content, true);
     el.parentNode.shadowRoot.appendChild(clone)
     el.remove()
```

Comment: У вас же в итоге разметка будет не валидной `div > li`

Comment: Это для примера. Мне это для серверного рендеринга надо. Я html получил, сейчас мне надо для гидрации в shadowRoot вставить элементы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если брать именно Вашу разметку, то можно сделать например вот так:

```
let div = document.querySelector('div');
document.querySelector('ul li').forEach(li => div.append(li));
document.querySelector('ul').remove()
```

Однако, конечно надежнее использовать идентификаторы а не типы элементов, в качестве селекторов...

—-

Если Вас устраивает потеря слушателей на перемещаемых элементах, можно еще сделать вот так:

```
let div = document.querySelector('div');
let ul = document.querySelector('ul');
div.innerHTML = ul.innerHTML;
ul.remove()
```

Comment: Да это хороший вариант. Но неужели нет варианта без цикла ?

Comment: @Sergey есть, если Вас устроит потеря слушателей, можно переместить весь innerHTML

Comment: el.parentNode.shadowRoot.innerhtml = el.childNodes
В shadowRoot не вставилось. 
Я Element.insertAdjacentHTML() использовать, не получается.

Comment: Про shadowRoot извиняюсь не написал.Варианты да, хорошие.

Comment: написал дополнения.

Однако, конечно надежнее использовать идентификаторы а не типы элементов, в качестве селекторов...

так и есть конечно. Я в тот момент <template> использовал, по этому написал такой пример. С темплейтами такой проблемы нет.